# When using Massive, how do you retrieve values from Out parameters of stored procedures?

Tags: massive

I've been testing Rob Conery's Massive ORM in some of my projects. I usually use stored procedures and Massive seems to work pretty well and makes it easy.

However, i can't figure out how to specify OUT parameters or how to retrieve those values through Massive.

Comment: Maybe its not possible? Thats what I'm guessing after 6 days with no answers.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to use output parameters with Massive?

Comment: Nope. I switched to using Dapper.

Comment: I hope this [link](https://github.com/robconery/massive/issues/67) will help your query.